# Resultado de busca com perguntas repetidas

Tags: bug, status-intencional

Fui fazer uma busca para "android" e ao retornar os resultados, o site está apresentando a mesma pergunta com P e R antes, e com as pontuações diferentes.

Quando clico em qualquer uma, está indo para a pergunta correta. 
Estou anexando um screenshot:

![Resultado da busca para Android][1].

Como comentado na resposta aceita, isso realmente não é um bug. Como não tinha visto esse comportamento no stackoverflow.com antes, pensei que era um bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O mesmo caso acontece no StackOverflow.com. Não se trata de um bug, a busca retorna os posts onde encontrou os termos pesquisados independente se eles são perguntas ou respostas, ou se eles compõe uma mesma questão.

Isso fica mais realçado no site atual porque ele possui uma quantidade pequenas de posts no acervo.

Comment: Olá @Guilherme, eu uso o stackoverfloq.com há um bom tempo e nunca tinha visto esse P: E R:. Depois da sua resposta e da outra abaixo, fui no site pesquisar pra ver e o comportamento é quase isso. Percebi que qnd se pesquisa por um termo que é uma tag, ele não faz isso, só quando é um termo "genérico". Valeu.

Comment: @Neto Marin, eu já tinha reparado. Acontece com mais frequência em assuntos com menos atividade. Olha aqui [um exemplo](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=alfresco+enterprise). Dá uma olhada nos primeiros resultados...

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o comportamento esteja correto. A com P antes se refere ao texto da pergunta. A outra, com R, se refere ao texto da resposta. Temos tão poucos resultados relevantes no momento que o sistema não tem opção exceto mostrar qualquer coisa que encontre.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>A pergunta já se encontra bem respondida, vou apenas adicionar opções para gerir os resultados de pesquisa.</sup>

Se não limitares a pesquisa, a mesma devolve tudo o que encontrar com a expressão introduzida, ou seja, perguntas [P] e respostas [R] que contenha a palavra ou palavras que procuras.

Mas podes fazer uso dos limitadores de pesquisa para melhorar os teus resultados e obteres uma pesquisa mais direccionada para o que pretendes:

Por exemplo, se pretendes obter apenas perguntas que contenham a tua expressão, passa o limitador de perguntas:

```
is:question
```

Para obteres apenas respostas:

```
is:answer
```

### Exemplo

Pesquisa por `android` limitada a perguntas:

```
android is:question
```

---

Se acederes à [Página de pesquisa avançada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search), podes ver na coluna lateral direita o link "Dicas de pesquisa avançada" que te vai apresentar uma lista de opções úteis para refinar os resultados:

```
┌────────────┬───────────────────────┐
│ tags       │ [tag]                 │ com tag X
├────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│ exato      │ "palavras aqui"       │ expressão exacta
├────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│ autor      │ user:1234             │ do utilizador X
│            │ user:me (seu)         │ tuas
├────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│ pontuação  │ score:3 (3+)          │ pontuação de X
│            │ score:0 (nenhum)      │ sem pontuação
├────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│ respostas  │ answers:3 (3+)        │ com X respostas
│            │ answers:0 (nenhum)    │ sem respostas
│            │ isaccepted:yes        │ com resposta aceite
│            │ hasaccepted:no        │ sem resposta aceite
│            │ inquestion:1234       │ procura no ID de pergunta X
├────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│ visitas    │ views:250             │ número de visitas
├────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│ seções     │ title:apples          │ título com...
│            │ body:"maçãs laranjas" │ corpo com...
├────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│ url        │ url:"*.example.com"   │ contém o URL X
├────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│ favoritos  │ infavorites:mine      │ nos teus favoritos
│            │ infavorites:1234      │ nos favoritos utilizador X
├────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│ status     │ closed:yes            │ está fechada
│            │ duplicate:no          │ é duplicada
│            │ migrated:no           │ é migrada
│            │ wiki:no               │ é wiki
├────────────┤───────────────────────┤
│ tipos      │ is:question           │ é pergunta
│            │ is:answer             │ é resposta
└────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```